# Box-shadow - top and left only

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

```
<div class="myContainer">
Some text...
</div>
```

Now I only want on the **left side** and the **top** of the element a box-shadow.
How can I do this?

I tried this:

```
.myContainer {
   box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use negative values for the positioning.

```
box-shadow: -10px -10px 5px 0px #888888;
```

Use a CSS3 generator to try it out, like [this one](http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow)

Remember to also include the vendor specific prefixes to ensure cross browser compatibility.

```
-webkit-box-shadow: -10px -10px 5px 0px #888888;
-moz-box-shadow: -10px -10px 5px 0px #888888;
```

You can check it out with this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n139sozy/)

If you want to know more about the `box-shadow` property, then check out [MDN box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)

Answer (score 1):

Like this, See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/7oe5kh9L/25/

1st number - is the horizontal position (negative is left, positive right)

2nd number - is the vertical position (negative is up, positive down)

3rd number - is the blur radius

4th number - is spread radius

```
  -webkit-box-shadow: -12px -9px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: -12px -9px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: -12px -9px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
```

HTML

```
<div class="someDiv"></div>
```

CSS

```
.someDiv {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightblue; 
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -12px -9px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: -12px -9px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: -12px -9px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
div
{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  left:45px;
  box-shadow:-10px -5px 4px #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
div{
  width:200px;
    height:200px;
  background-color:red;
  margin:50px;
  box-shadow:-10px -5px 4px #ccc;
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```